# How to import youtube video playlist video links and titles to google sheets?

Tags: youtube, playlist

I request help in importing Youtube playlist videos link with their title to google sheets

Answer (score 0):

please check if the below link helps to your need

https://zapier.com/apps/excel/integrations/youtube